# determining the properties used by a previous build

Tags: qbs

After some time, I went to a project to redo a build and the command I give results in:

```
qbs build -p archive config:release modules.cpp.useRPaths:false
Restoring build graph from disk
ERROR: Property values set on the command line differ from the ones used for the previous build. Use the 'resolve' command if you really want to rebuild with the new properties.
```

Is there any way to determine which properties were set in the previous build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the command-line frontend does not expose this functionality. But independent of that, it would be helpful if the error message listed the differing properties. You might want to create a task for that at bugreports.qt.io.

Comment: I submitted a patch that helped me a lot here: https://github.com/giallu/qbs/tree/show_cached_properties I hope it will included in the project